# Can't click on link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

I've uploaded my website, so you can see how it works, and also can check the CSS there. It's not fully working, but the problem is visible. http://exampleforso.uw.hu/testvertaboraink.html

My problem is that I can't click the link on the page. Anyone can help me correct my code?

I'm still new to CSS, so my code might be messy or imperfect. And sorry for the language its hungarian.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Gonna do it next time, thank you for suggestion. I assumed the code is too long, to post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#menuwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 212px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto; /* or just remove */
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

You set a top value AND a bottom value of 0, with no height. The browser will fill that space up. This means that the menu wrapper will be on top of the rest of the content, so when you think you are clicking on the link, you're actually clicking on the menu wrapper.

You should get rid of all those position absolutes, or at least get some better z-indexing going so that the "3D" representation is correct.

Comment: This is the correct answer AND has a good explanation (AND was submitted before mine). way to make the rest of us look like chumps

Answer (score 0):

Give your menuwrapper a fixed height. Something like this:

```
#menuwrapper {
    height: 45px;
}
```

or remove the "z-index" that you have given to the menuwrapper.

Currently, your menuwrapper has a height of 430px and along with the z-index it makes the link, unclickable.

---

Update: Removing the "bottom" value is the right solution.

Comment: working thank you! gonna vote up, if i have enough reputation. any other suggestions?

Comment: This is wrong, well it works but this is not what you should do. This doesn't deal with the actual problem. You can leave the height at auto, but you need to remove bottom: 0;. (See my post for the explanation.)

Comment: If you right click on your menuwrapper and select "Inspect element". You will see the CSS on the right hand side. If you set manually a height or disable the z-index, then your link will be clickable.

Comment: @BramVanroy Yes Bram you are right. Your answer is more correct. I hadn't noticed that the menuwrapper had been given a 'bottom' value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your header has a height of 700px and position absolute, which means it overlaps not only your link, but you whole page, So either remove the height or the position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

In your `styletest.css` file.

From `#menuwrapper` Remove the property `z-index:1;`

And it will work perfectly.

What's happening here is, your div that contains that link is getting overlapped by the div with `id=menuwrapper`. And both those divs have `z-index` property set to 1.

Removing that from `#menuwrapper` should fix the problem.

You should not really play with height values as that may distort your orientation and alignment should you open that website on screen that is huge.

Comment: That will cause the hover menus to display behind the content.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `bottom:0` rule from your `#menuwrapper` CSS block. this will allow the menu wrapper to assume the correct height as dictated by its contents.

This way, you don't need to declare a specific height (which would change with things like font size, etc.) or change your z-index, which allows your menu flyouts to correctly display above the page content.